# pasar información de un QDialog a su padre QMainWindow

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

Tengo una clase que hereda de la clase `QMainWindow` y dicha clase contiene a otra clase creada por mi que hereda de `QDialog`. Quisiera que al dar click en un boton al `QDialog` este capturara la información que hay en un `QLineEdit` y se la enviara a su padre para que este lo procese. Aqui dejo un ejemplo de código:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('añadir')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.add)

        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add(self):
        print('se ha añadido {}'.format(self.line.text()))


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.setWindowTitle('window')

        self.label = QLabel('aqui se muestra la informacion del dialog')
        self.btn = QPushButton('abrir dialog')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.dialog.show)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

lo que quiero es que cuando se da un click en el boton añadir del `Dialog` este se cierre y en el label de `Window` muestre el texto del QLineEdit

Answer (score 2):

Hace unas semanas estaba programando una app en PyQt5 y me topé con el mismo problema. Luego de pasar por varias ideas me quedé con la siguiente:

- Reimplementar el método `accept` de `QDialog`
- Guardar las respuestas en un diccionario dentro del dialogo
- "Rescatar" las respuestas luego de llamar al dialogo

Lo que tengo yo en mi programa es:

```
class Formulario(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, calendar=None):
        ...
        self.initUi()


    def initUi(self):
        ...
        btnAddHorario = QPushButton(QIcon(":/i/add_black"), "Agregar Horario")
        btnAddHorario.clicked.connect(self.agregarHorario)
        ...

    def agregarHorario(self):
        dialogo = NuevoHorarioDialog(self)
        if dialogo.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
            newhorario = Horario(dialogo.POST['dia'], dialogo.POST['desde'], dialogo.POST['hasta'])
            self.horarios.append(newhorario)

class NuevoHorarioDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.POST = {}
        self.initUi()


    def initUi(self):
        ...
        btnOk = QPushButton('Agregar')
        btnOk.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        ...

    def accept(self):
        self.POST['dia'] = self.cbDia.currentIndex()
        self.POST['desde'] = self.desdeTP.time().toString()
        self.POST['hasta'] = self.hastaTP.time().toString()
        super().accept()
```

Extracto (copy/paste) de mi programa.

Comment: interesante tu propuesta, lo probaré. Te tengo otra pregunta poco relacionada con mi pregunta: algunas documentaciones dicen que todas las variables se deben declarar en el `__init__`, otras sugieren que el estandár es usar un método `initUi` para la inicialización de las variables visuales y dejar solo el `__init__` para las variables lógicas.

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila Claro. El método `initUi` lo ocupo para definir todo lo que se muestra por pantalla, los botones, inputs, la manera en que estos estén ordenados, etc, e `__init__` para el resto.